# send.keys partially working using python on selenium

Tags: python, selenium, sendkeys

I am working on sending some unique strings in a UI (HTML based) using Python in selenium. I just released that for some cases, the string is partially sent to UI and NOT the complete line. I am using send.keys command. I guess the code is sending the string too fast and its not getting it captured completely in the UI.

is there another way i can send this dynamic string as a complete line?

Comment: Can you share your code trial and relevant HTML?

Comment: driver.find_element_by_xpath("//*[@id='entGridView_denyPopup_float_modalPopupPanel_txtCustomDenyNotes']").send_keys(final_note)                                                                               final_note is the text value (string) that i am adding in the UI.

Answer (score 0):

**try this maybe
from time import sleep**

```
from time import sleep
```

**and use the :**

```
sleep()
```